Mapbox's SymbolLayer in React Native Doesn't Work
I want to draw the path of the route but with arrows on the line. I did some research and found out that we need to put two layers: one for the line and one for the arrows. I did. The good thing is that the line shows up perfectly, but  the arrows on the map don't show up at all. I used the LineLayer for the line and SymbolLayer for the arrows. On the map on the first arrow shows up. This is my code:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {StyleSheet,View} from 'react-native';
import Mapbox, {MapView, ShapeSource, LineLayer, PointAnnotation, SymbolLayer, Images} from '@rnmapbox/maps';

Mapbox.setAccessToken('<PUBLIC_TOKEN>');

const arrowImage = require('./assets/arrow.png');

const App = () => {

  const [data] = useState({
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {},
        "geometry": {
          "type": "LineString",
          "coordinates": [
            [-72.59507, 46.32814],
            [-72.595047, 46.328358],
            [-72.595078, 46.328392],
            [-72.596489, 46.330627],
            [-72.621262, 46.343796],
            [-72.63372, 46.35133],
            [-72.634834, 46.351959],
            [-72.641441, 46.355686],
            [-72.668472, 46.3745],
            [-72.675148, 46.375626],
            [-72.671448, 46.370411]
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  });

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView
        style={styles.container}
        > 
        <Images
              images={{someIcon1: require('./assets/test.png')}}
            />
        <ShapeSource id='line' shape={data}>
          <LineLayer id='linelayer' style={{lineColor:'green'}} />
          </ShapeSource>
          <ShapeSource id='line' shape={data}>
          <SymbolLayer
              id="symbolLocationSymbols"
              aboveLayer={'linelayer3'}
              minZoomLevel={1}
              style={{
                iconImage: 'someIcon1',
                iconSize: 0.25,
                iconOffset: [0, -32],
                iconAllowOverlap: true
              }}
            />
        </ShapeSource>
      </MapView>
    </View>
  );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});

export default App;

I tried following the documentation but there are no examples on there mostly.
